# Possible mistake in article proving every Riemannian manifold admits a conformal complete metric

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

In ["The existence of complete Riemannian metrics."](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1961-012-06/S0002-9939-1961-0133785-8/S0002-9939-1961-0133785-8.pdf), by Nomizu, Katsumi, and Hideki Ozeki, the authors prove that every Riemannian manifold admits a complete metric which is also conformal to the original one. The proof starts like this:

[image]

Isn't the statement "if $r(x) = \infty$ at some point $x$, $M$ is compact" plainly false? A counter example would be $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard metric, where $r(x) =  \infty$ for every point but $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not compact. I tried to use this argument in an exam and my professor mentioned it was wrong because of this, but I want to make sure I'm not misunderstanding anything.

Comment: Yes, this is a small error. Instead they should have said "if ()=∞ for some point , then  is complete by the Hopf-Rinow theorem." They also forgot to assume that $M$ is connected.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks! Can you explain how it would follow from Hopf Rinow that $M$ is complete?

Comment: I think it would be because every closed and bounded set could be expressed as a finite union of these compact neighbourhoods, is that right?

Comment: That's right...